# WCF rest client - Post timeout

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I am newbie to WCF rest. I have two operation contracts, a POST and GET Method.
In my client, i use HttpWebRequest and try to access the operation contract.

Whenever i access the POST method operation contract i get a timeout error.
But when i try accessing the POST method after a successful GET method, everything works fine.

Is it necessary, that i should use GET method call subsequent to a POST method call?

What wrong am i doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a GET before a POST is not necessary. Your error might not actually be a POST timeout but rather bad data going to the server and the server failing on deserialization.

Is it possible that the GET is setting up some data on the client that travels back to the server? If this is the case then, is it possible for that data that the GET sets to be the data that when unset, makes the POST fail on the server?

The best way to find out is to set tracing on your server. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) for good examples of WCF tracing.

**UPDATE**: Another possibility is that your GET code is initializing something on the server side that your POST call is missing. Perhaps a DB connection?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, will try and revert to you. A quick verification btw, if the data send via POST is bad, it shd fail even after accessing via GET method right.. but how come that works?

Comment: unless you are using the GET to load data that gets sent in the post later. In that case it is possible that your request has more stuff in it? It is difficult to say with the details from your question, just throwing out suggestions. However, in general the requests are stateless, so the GET and POST should NOT interact at all.

Comment: I tried accessing my rest service, using Httpwebrequest and JsonSerialization, my post works without any problem. I have another client which uses servicemodel.clientbase to access my service. in this case, when i access the post method, i get a timeout. is there any setting i am missing here. Is using clientbase to access rest service is correct?

Comment: I've never used clientbase for REST but here's an example: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-rest-client-using-wcf

Comment: now that I think of it, I'm not sure that it makes complete sense to use REST here. If you have your own service and are trying to write a client for it, it will be far easier to use SOAP (generate proxies, etc). You can also have a REST and SOAP endpoint defined for the same service and just make the contracts function as a facade to the actual logic running the operations.

Comment: thanks for your help ale.. looking forward more support from you in future.. I have decided to stick to HttpWebRequest..